# Converting C code snippet to MIPS Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, mips

as part of a homework assignment we're required to convert the following code snippet from C to MIPS Assembly:

```
for (i=0; i<A; i++) { 
    for (j=0; j<B; j++) {  
        C[4 * j] = i + j;  
        }  
}
```

I believe I have the logic down and most of the code is correct. I'm just stuck at the line: `D[4 * j] = i + j;`. I know how to get the sum of `i` and `j`, but I'm not sure how to actually put it into a multiple of its j address. Could someone please tell me what I'm missing in loop2? Thanks

```
.data
A: .word 2
B: .word 5
D: .word 0 : 100
size: .word 100

.text
    .globl  main
main:

    lw, $s0, A      #$s0 = A
    addi $s0, $s0, -1   #Allows for loop to properly run
    lw $s1, B       #$s1 = B
    addi $s1, $s1, -1   #Allows for loop to properly run
        la $s5, C           # load address of array
        li $t0, 0       #i = 0
        li $t1, 0       #j = 0
        
loop1:
    
    blt $s0, $t0, Exit  #for(i = 0; i < A; i++)
    addi $t0, $t0, 1    #i++
    li $t1, 0       #Sets j to 0 before calling loop2
    j loop2         #Calls loop2

loop2:

    blt $s0, $t0, loop1 #for(j = 0; j < B; j++)
    addi $t2, $t0, -1   #Allows to properly perform loop
    {Where I'm confused what to do}

    
    
    {Last two steps of loop2}
    addi $t1, $t1, 1    #j++
    j loop2
    
Exit:
      # The program is finished. Exit.
      li   $v0, 10          # system call for exit
      syscall               # Exit!
```

Comment: `blt $s0, $t0, loop1` is wrong because you want `$s1` for `B`. `addi $t2, $t0, -1 ` is useless as `$t2`is not mentioned anywhere else. As to your question remember that `A[x]` is just `*(A+x)` and that you need to scale by item size.

Answer (score 2):

Your assembly code barely resembles the C equivalent you're showing.  For example, there is no `-1` in the C code, yet used multiple times in the assembly code!

Thus, you have gone down the classic error-prone approach of hyper-optimizing your code ***during translation from C to assembly***.  This is a very error prone process, and also unnecessary!!

The best way to do this pointer and loop optimization is to do it all in C first!  We can express many, many optimizations such as these and others in C directly!  Then test it in C to make sure it works, only then take to assembly knowing that at least the algorithm works!

Comment: @Jester, yes, my bad; I missed that; have removed suggestion otherwise.

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your reply! I included what I thought was the most important part of the code, but I have tested it in C and it does work. I just don't know how to approach the second loop for the line D[4 * j] = i + j;

Comment: If you tested that -1 stuff in C, why did you not post that version of the C instead of posting the original?

Comment: It's an assignment, the target of the assignment is an array element, presumably a word-sized element, so that will be a `sw` instruction.  Will need to compute both `i+j` and `4*j`.  Because it is an assignment to a word sized array element, will need to scale `4*j` by element size.  So, compute `4*j*4` or `16*j` then add to `C` to produce the intermediate pointer value to use for the address to store into with `sw`.